# Positive integrable function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Darboux integrable, and let $a\leq c<d\leq b$ such that $f$ is positive in $[c,d]$, and $f$ is not continuous in $[c,d]$. Does this necessarily imply that $\int\limits_{c}^df(x)dx > 0$?

Obviously this is true for continuous functions (even if the function is continuous at one point).

Comment: By Lebesgue's criterion $f$ is continuous at least at some $x\in [c,d]$...

Comment: I see. Because the discontinuities of $f$ is of measure 0, and $[c,d]$ is not of measure 0, $f$ must have at least one continuity point in $[c,d]$, right?